# filter search in array object, in selected keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I need some suggestion or the best way to get it to array data filter with the passed value. 
Currently, I have

```
let arrayobject = [
{"name": "apple", "type": "juice-material", "srnum": 123234},
{"name": "cranberry", "type": "desert-material", "srnum": 98989},
{"name": "grapes", "type": "wine-material", "srnum":656565}]
```

if I passed `apple` then return array will be

```
[{"name": "apple", "type": "juice-material", "srnum": 123234}]
```

if I passed `wine-material`
   return result

```
{"name": "grapes", "type": "wine-material", "srnum":656565}
```

similarly for srnum, while passing it gives filter array object result.

Currently,

I have tried using

```
_.some(arrayobject, _.unary(_.partialRight(_.includes, passedValue)))
```

it gives context result, but not predictable.

Let me know the best possible way to filter the data.
Thanks.

Comment: with toLowerCase filter

`data.filter(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()))`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think your approach is pretty much the best. However, you use [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#some) which will merely give a boolean result if any item matches, if you swap it with [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) you can get all items that match or you can change for [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find) to just get the first one:

```js
let arrayobject = [
  {"name": "apple",     "type": "juice-material",  "srnum": 123234},
  {"name": "cranberry", "type": "desert-material", "srnum": 98989},
  {"name": "grapes",    "type": "wine-material",   "srnum": 656565}
]

function filterByValues(collection, whatToSearchFor) {
  //separating just for easier readability
  let predicate = _.unary(_.partialRight(_.includes, whatToSearchFor));
  
  return _.filter(collection, predicate);
}

//matches a value
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "apple"));
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "wine-material"));
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, 98989));

//doesn't match a key
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "name"));
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "type"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With that said, @georg points out in a comment that you can re-write this using less Lodash functionality and just a plain callback with [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#includes) - this *might* be a bit more readable than using `_.partialRight` and `_.unary`:

```js
let arrayobject = [
  {"name": "apple",     "type": "juice-material",  "srnum": 123234},
  {"name": "cranberry", "type": "desert-material", "srnum": 98989},
  {"name": "grapes",    "type": "wine-material",   "srnum": 656565}
]

function filterByValues(collection, whatToSearchFor) {
  //separating just for easier readability
  let predicate = item => _.includes(item, whatToSearchFor);
  
  return _.filter(collection, predicate);
}

//matches a value
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "apple"));
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "wine-material"));
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, 98989));

//doesn't match a key
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "name"));
console.log(filterByValues(arrayobject, "type"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Finally someone bothered to read the question ;) Though I'm not sure the unary/partial cascade is more readable than simply `_.filter(..., x => _.includes(x, search))`

Comment: @georg I can't really say, either. It's all the same to me but perhaps different people will have different opinions. I just re-used OP's code. But you do have a point and I'll add it to this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayobject.filter()` to filter on desired prop

```js
let arrayobject = [
{"name": "apple", "type": "juice-material", "srnum": 123234},
{"name": "cranberry", "type": "desert-material", "srnum": 98989},
{"name": "grapes", "type": "wine-material", "srnum":656565}]

var res = arrayobject.filter(x => x.name == "apple");
console.log(res);

var res2 = arrayobject.filter(x => x.type == "wine-material");
console.log(res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The filter can be applied as follows:**

```js
function filterItems(items, searchVal) {
  return items.filter((item) => Object.values(item).includes(searchVal));
}
let arrayobject = [
  { "name": "apple", "type": "juice-material", "srnum": 123234 },
  { "name": "cranberry", "type": "desert-material", "srnum": 98989 },
  { "name": "grapes", "type": "wine-material", "srnum": 656565 }]


console.log("Filtered by name: ", filterItems(arrayobject, "apple"));
console.log("Filtered by type: ", filterItems(arrayobject, "desert-material"));
console.log("Filtered by srnum: ", filterItems(arrayobject, 656565));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flatMap** with the required array.
All you need to give properties which you want to find.

In your case it is

```js
    let arrayobject = [
    {"name": "apple", "type": "juice-material", "srnum": 123234},
    {"name": "cranberry", "type": "desert-material", "srnum": 98989},
    {"name": "grapes", "type": "wine-material", "srnum":656565}]
    
    var filteredData = getFilterData(arrayobject, 656565);
    console.log(filteredData);
    function getFilterData(array, searchValue){            
           return array.flatMap(obj => obj)
                  .find(({ name,type,srnum }) => (name === searchValue || type == searchValue) 
                  || srnum == searchValue);            
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` on your array Object. The [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
arrayobject.filter(data => {
return (data.name && data.name.includes(value)) ||
       (data.type && data.type.includes(value)) ||
       (data.srnum && data.srnum.includes(value))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter objects from array, which contains the value in any on the key then you can directly use an [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#includes)  in each object to filter ( [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter)) them out from array. in case you need to look on a specific set of keys, just use `_.pick` before passing the object to includes.

```js
let array = [
              {id: 1, x: 'XX1', y: 'YY1', z: 'ZZ1'},
              {id: 2, x: 'XX1', y: 'YY2', z: 'ZZ2'},
              {id: 3, x: 'ZZ2', y: 'YY3', z: 'ZZ1'},
            ],
      filterByValue = (a, v) => _.filter(a, e => _.includes(e, v)),
      filterByValueInKeys = (a, v, keys) => _.filter(a, e => _.includes(_.pick(e, keys), v));
      
console.log('ZZ1: ', filterByValue(array, 'ZZ1'));
console.log('ZZ2: ', filterByValue(array, 'ZZ2'));

console.log('ZZ1 within x,y: ', filterByValueInKeys(array, 'ZZ1', ['x', 'y']));
console.log('ZZ2 within x,y: ', filterByValueInKeys(array, 'ZZ2', ['x', 'y']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```